# Is it possible to do region based spellcheck in vim?

Tags: vim

Emacs has ispell-word, ispell-region commands, which spellcheck current word, current selected region. Do we have such equivalent in vim?
I find this is useful to spell check a particular block of code comments.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Spelling in Vim is syntax-based. That is, for various programming languages it is enabled *exactly for all comments*. Simply toggle `:h 'spell'` option for the current buffer and, assuming syntax is on, it just works.

See also `:h :syn-spell` and `:h spell.txt`